# how to properly join and query to achieve comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I have 2 tables (OITM and artfileStatus).  I want to join them on `OITM.ItemCode = artfileStatus.artfilename + ‘.pdf’`

I want to query the OITM table to return a list of all `OITM.ItemCodes` in that table.  As an additional column, I want to find out which `OITM.ItemCodes` do not exist in `artfileStatus.artfilename + ‘.pdf’`

If the `(artfileStatus.artfilename + ‘.pdf’ )` doesn’t exist, I’d like to return the text “No artwork”.  If the `(artfileStatus.artfilename + ‘.pdf’  )` does exist, I’d like to return the value for `(artfileStatus.filelocation)`.

I am unsure of either the correct join to use and/or the proper way to query this.  I'm sure CASE is involved in the select statement, but I'm finding that my query attempts are not returning any results at all when the `artfileStatus.artfilename + ‘.pdf’` does not exist.

Can you help point me in the right direction or offer a sample solution based on this information?  Thanks so much!

Comment: what is the query you tried?

Comment: This is reduced from a more complicated query but hopefully matches the simpler version that I asked, but here is what I've tried:

SELECT DISTINCT T0.[ItemCode], 

CASE 
                  WHEN t4.artfilename is null
                     THEN 'No artwork'  
                  ELSE t4.filelocation
             END as 'File Status'

FROM OITM T0 inner join UFD1 t1 on t0.U_status = t1.fldvalue and t1.tableid = 'oitm' and t1.fieldid = 13

INNER JOIN artfileStatus T4 on t0.itemcode + '.pdf' = t4.artfilename

WHERE t0.U_Status between '09' and '18'

Group by T0.ItemCode, t4.artfilename

Comment: if you do an inner join, you will only get back the matching records. If you do a left outer join, then all the rows from the left table will be used, and when no match in the right table is found, a null row is used, hence both my (now deleted) and other answers used an left join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemCode,
       CASE WHEN artfilename IS NULL
       THEN 'NoArtwork'
       ELSE fileLocation
       END
FROM OITM
LEFT OUTER JOIN  artfileStatus ON OITM.ItemCode = SUBSTRING(artfileStatus.artfilename , 1, 6)
```

Comment: When I try this query, I get the error:  1). [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '‘'.   So I changed the very last part to '.pdf' and it allows the query to run.  However, while this does return every ItemCode in OITM (as I hoped), it incorrectly returns "NoArtwork" for every item.  Please note that ItemCode in OITM looks like this "102-13" where as in the artfileStatus table it looks like this "102-13.pdf"

Comment: You can use substring on the artfile status to get just string without the pdf. I updated my code and I assumed the status will always contain 6 characters.